# Quid velit "Quid tibi vidétur dé [aliquó]" dícere?

Tags: idiom, sentence-translation

Epistólió in electronicó quídam mihi sic scrípsit: "Quid tibi vidétur dé Epistuliís Leónínís?" (Epistulæ Leónínæ acta sunt hebdomadália ab eó missa, quás nóndum vídí.)

Sententia (síve phrasis) "Quid tibi vidétur dé [néscióquó]" mihi ignóta est. Quid velit dícere?

(Hóc in linguá Latíná scríptó, cernó sérius respónsum anglicum potius quam latínum mihi conveníre…)

Comment: Btw since you're marking vowel lengths: velit has short e, and sic and sive have long i.

Comment: @TKR Thanks yet again! I've fixed *velit* and *sive*. *Sic,* unless I'm mistaken (I may be), is usually marked long because it used to be *sicce* and long not by nature but by position.

Comment: I think the vowel of *sic* is long. There are alternative spellings *seic* and *sīce* (the latter marked with long i in L&S), and it's derived from *sī*.

Answer (score 6):

I take it to mean "What do you think about X?" or "What is your opinion of X?".

Literally, "What seems to you [sc. to be the case] about X?"

I'm not sure if I've seen this expression in Latin authors, but it strikes me as idiomatic. There are other languages (including I think Romance languages) which have a similar idiom.

(Btw, I can't understand the last sentence of your question.)

Comment: Thanks! I intended the last sentence to mean (clunkily translated), "This question having been written in Latin, I realize too late that an English rather than a Latin answer would suit me better."

Comment: (Please suggest improvements if any occur to you!)

Comment: @JoelDerfner In that case I think you need either scripto or rogato but not both, and an infinitive instead of conveniat.

Comment: D'oh! I'll correct.

Comment: I agree. Cf. Greek *dokei moi*.